# Iframe that works with Div Button

Tags: javascript, css, iframe

I have an image that is inside a div.
The image is a play button.
On top of the image I have placed an iframe which is invisible.
When I click the image I want the iframe to appear and start playing

ok i think i found a code that is supposed to do the same thing but i cant make it work

```
<img src="http://www.plaisio.gr/Images/Promo/20140808-Promo-Turbo-X-Pi/turbox-pi_promo_v01_03.jpg" alt="" style="display:block;" name="video" id="video" height="272" width="495"> <iframe id="promo_video" src="" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen="" style="display:none;position:absolute;top:175px;left:344px;" frameborder="0" height="272" width="495"></iframe>




   <script type="text/javascript">
$('img#video').click(function(){
$(this).parent().parent().find('#promo_video').attr('src','http://player.vimeo.com/video/102923007?autoplay=true');
$(this).parent().parent().find('#promo_video').fadeIn('slow');
})
</script>
```

but its not working.... any help??
i found a simmilar working example here http://www.plaisio.gr/Campaign/20140808-Turbo-x-Smartphone-P.htm

Comment: is that a typo or did you forget the quotes around `visible` and `display`? ie  `= "visible";` or are they actual variables? Also if they are meant to be actual values `display` is not a valid value for `style.display`, _block,inline-block,inline,hidden_ etc are though

Answer (score 1):

In your html you dont need the button, just add `onclick="myFunction();"` to your `<img>`

In your css you should only have `display:none`, not `visibility: hidden`

In you javascript `document.getElementsByClassName("video")` returns an array. Try this:

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("video")[0];
    x.style.display = "block";
}
```

Check it out here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7y0w68sb/)